# How to change locally background for beamer section?

Tags: beamer, templates, backgrounds, beamer-metropolis

I use `metropolis` beamer theme for my presentation.
With it I change the background to add a watermark.
But I would like to switch to another background on section slides.
So I tried different things (see the following MWE) without any success. None of my attemps change the background nor gave the expected result.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    % Metropolis Theme
    \usetheme{metropolis}
        \metroset{
            sectionpage= progressbar,
            subsectionpage= progressbar, 
            numbering=fraction,
        }

    % Background redefinition
    \setbeamertemplate{background}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
           \fill[color=orange] (0,7) rectangle(0.8,8);     
           \fill[color=blue] (0.9,7) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8);
       \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    % Section style
%   % First try not working because it keeps the previous background
%   \addtobeamertemplate{section page}{%
%       \setbeamertemplate*{background}{%
%           \begin{tikzpicture}
%                rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);     
%              \fill[color=red] (0.9,7) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8);
%          \end{tikzpicture}
%       }    
%   }
    
%   % Second try not working because it has no effect
%   \addtobeamertemplate{section page}{%
%       \usebackgroundtemplate{
%           \begin{tikzpicture}
%           rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);     
%            \fill[color=red] (0.9,7) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8);
%          \end{tikzpicture}
%       }
%   }

    % Third try not working because it kills the style of metropolis
    \defbeamertemplate{background}{section}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
             rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);     
           \fill[color=red] (0.9,7) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8);
       \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \addtobeamertemplate{section page}{%
        \usebeamertemplate*{background}[section]
    }

\begin{document}

        \begin{frame}{Test}
            Test
        \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction}

        \begin{frame}{Test}
            Test
        \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

So how to redefine locally the background in the sections slides while keeping the metropolis section style ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite being a wonderful package, the existing interfaces of `beamer` still fail to fulfill the need of advanced customization. However, the framework of beamer allows one to implement custom hacks and workarounds to achieve almost everything one can think of. The process may be a little bit time-consuming though. Let me lay out how I investigate this problem and come up with a solution.

1. The CTAN page for the `metropolis` theme is https://ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-metropolis?lang=en. This page provides you with the access to its source code and documentation. From its documentation, I realize that the `sectionpage` option is part of its *inner theme* mechanism. Therefore, this points me to one of its source file: `beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx`.
2. From the source file mentioned above, we can extract the following code segments of interest. Basically, section pages are implemented by calling the `\sectionpage` macro.

   ```latex
   \pgfkeys{
     /metropolis/inner/sectionpage/.cd,
       .is choice,
       none/.code=\metropolis@disablesectionpage,
       simple/.code={\metropolis@enablesectionpage
                     \setbeamertemplate{section page}[simple]},
       progressbar/.code={\metropolis@enablesectionpage
                          \setbeamertemplate{section page}[progressbar]},
   }

   \newcommand{\metropolis@enablesectionpage}{
     \AtBeginSection{
       \ifbeamer@inframe
         \sectionpage
       \else
         \frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{\sectionpage}
       \fi
     }
   }
   ```
3. We can continue to look at the definition of `\sectionpage` command by simply typing `\meaning\sectionpage`. The output is `macro:->\usebeamertemplate *{section page}`, which means `\sectionpage` invokes a predefined template called `section page`, which eventually triggers background drawing commands. Therefore, to solve this problem, we can modify the `\AtBeginSection` block so that a global variable is introduced to keep track of whether the current frame is a section frame or not. The background drawing function should behave based on this variable.

In the end, the solution is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Metropolis Theme
\usetheme{metropolis}
\metroset{
    sectionpage= progressbar,
    subsectionpage= progressbar, 
    numbering=fraction,
}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn


% marks if title page
\bool_new:N \g_doc_tp_bool
\bool_gset_false:N \g_doc_tp_bool

\AtBeginSection{
    \bool_gset_true:N \g_doc_tp_bool
    \ifbeamer@inframe
      \sectionpage
    \else
      \frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{\sectionpage}
    \fi
    \bool_gset_false:N \g_doc_tp_bool
}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
   \bool_if:NTF \g_doc_tp_bool {
       % title page
       \begin{tikzpicture}
           \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
           \fill[color=green] (6,7) circle (1cm);     
       \end{tikzpicture}
   } {
        % non title page
       \begin{tikzpicture}
           \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\the\paperheight);
           \fill[color=orange] (0,7) rectangle(0.8,8);     
           \fill[color=blue] (0.9,7) rectangle(\the\paperwidth, 8);
       \end{tikzpicture}
   }

}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}            % balise de début de la présentation

        \begin{frame}{Test}
            Test
        \end{frame}

    \section{Introduction}

        \begin{frame}{Test}
            Test
        \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I will test it soon, but it seems interesting !